# why isnt this counter method working correctly?

Tags: javascript

I have a count method and its print a bunch of ones to the console instead of adding a 1 to the num property for example if i past 1 into the argument I would get 100 ones instead of 1 through 100.

```
    let obj={
        num:0,
        count: function(max){
            for(let i=0; i<max; i++){
                let num=this.num;
                num++
                console.log(num);
            }
        }
    }

    obj.count(100);
```

Comment: you aren't reassigning `this.num`

Comment: what is the *objective* ?

Comment: Add this `this.num = num` after the line `num++`

Comment: None object types like,  string / number in javascript are passed by value, not reference..  So your `let num=this.num` is making a copy of `this.num`, and any changes only effect this copy.

Comment: declare `let num=this.num;` before for loop, you are done.

Answer (score 2):

It is not working correctly, because you are changing the value of the local variable `num` and not the instance variable `this.num`, so each iteration of the `for` loop `this.num` equals `0`. As the number is a value type it is not passed by reference. A simple fix can be implemented:

```
    let obj={
    num:0,
    count: function(max){
        for(let i=0; i<max; i++){
            this.num++
            console.log(this.num);
        }
    }
}

obj.count(100);
```

Comment: addition to post, If you don't want to change the `num` field declare this before for loop `let num=this.num;`.

Comment: This wouldn't work as you are not passing a reference to `num`, you are assigning the same value as `this.num`. Numbers are primitive types and assigning a variable to a number will set a value, but not pass a reference.